# Shell script to list locked packages in FreeBSD

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, freebsd

I'm trying to make a oneliner to be able to list all locked (forbidden to upgrade) packages in FreeBSD.

Normally, you issue this command:

```
pkg info -ak
```

It outputs list of all packages in system including locked and unlocked which isn't working for me as I only want locked ones. If I grep 'yes' it does exactly what I want:

```
pkg info -ak | grep yes
```

It outputs following:

```
nginx-devel-1.5.10             yes
php5-extensions-1.7            yes
php55-5.5.8                    yes
```

Now, what I want is to be able to edit that output a little bit by changing string 'yes' for following (*adding package name w/ version omitted*):

```
nginx-devel-1.5.10             locked, run: sudo pkg unlock nginx-devel
php5-extensions-1.7            locked, run: sudo pkg unlock php5-extensions
php55-5.5.8                    locked, run: sudo pkg unlock php55
```

I tried following unsuccessfully:

```
pkg info -ak | grep yes | sed s/yes/"locked - run: sudo pkg unlock $(pkg info -ak | grep yes | cut -d - f1-2)"/
```

While what I've tried isn't working I posted it just for you to get the idea what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pkg info -ak | grep -w yes | while read line; do packnum=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`; pack=`echo $packnum | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="-"}{$NF=""; NF--; print}'` ; printf "%-33s%s\n" "$packnum" "locked, run: sudo pkg unlock$pack" ;done
```

I added `-w` option to your `grep` to avoid confusion with packages containing "yes" in their name string.

Comment: Hey @Slyx this is the output i get:
`nginx-devel-1.5.10   locked, run: sudo pkg unlock devel 1.5.10`

So first package name field is missing and package version isn't omitted. Any chance of sorting those? Thanks man, appreciate it!

Comment: Indeed ! I fixed the mistake, please see my edit !

Answer (score 2):

The pkg command has been updated since this answer and pkg lock -l will produce the list of locked packages:

```
$ pkg lock -l
Currently locked packages:
compat11x-amd64-11.2.1102000.20181014
phantomjs-2.1.1_15
```

and

```
man pkg-lock
```

will give the details in any up-to-date version of FreeBSD.

For modern versions of FreeBSD, `pkg lock` and `awk` can provide your solution:

```
$ pkg lock -l |
  tail +2 |
  awk '{print $1}' |
  awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="-"} {\
    printf "%-33s locked, run: sudo pkg unlock ", $0; NF--; \
    printf "%s\n", $0 \
  }'
```

Output:

```
compat11x-amd64-11.2.1102000.20181014 locked, run: sudo pkg unlock compat11x-amd64
phantomjs-2.1.1_15                locked, run: sudo pkg unlock phantomjs
```

Note also, however, that removing the package version number is not necessary.  `pkg unlock` will accept the full package name, including the version number.  Hence, this simpler syntax is equally usable in terms of the unlocking actions recommended:

```
$ pkg lock -l |
  tail +2 |
  awk '{printf "%-33s locked, run: sudo pkg unlock %s\n", $1, $1}'
```

Output:

```
compat11x-amd64-11.2.1102000.20181014 locked, run: sudo pkg unlock compat11x-amd64-11.2.1102000.20181014
phantomjs-2.1.1_15                locked, run: sudo pkg unlock phantomjs-2.1.1_15
```

Comment: How can the OP use this to get the output they want? … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).